# I've Mixed values in a column (string+float) in data frame how can i change them to object

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame where few of columns have mixed type values string + float and when I'm writing them to_excel getting this notification after writing in excel [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2pmD.png)

this is the dataframe

```
df = placementsummaryfinalnew.loc[:,["Placement# Name","PRODUCT","Engagements Rate",
                                                                "Viewer CTR","Engager CTR","Viewer VCR",
                                                                "Engager VCR","Interaction Rate","Active Time Spent"]]
```

I tried to convert them by using few of lines

```
placementvdxsummaryfirst["Viewer VCR"] = placementvdxsummaryfirst["Viewer VCR"].astype(object)
```

its not working

then I tried this one.

```
placementvdxsummaryfirst["Viewer VCR"] = placementvdxsummaryfirst["Viewer VCR"].astype(float)
```

its giving error

then I tried this one.

```
placementvdxsummaryfirst['Viewer VCR'] = pd.to_numeric(placementvdxsummaryfirst['Viewer VCR'],errors='coerce')
```

its working but its replacing the "N/A" values with blanks which I don't want.

Kindly help.

Comment: '.astype(str)'?

Comment: not working as expected

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
placementvdxsummaryfirst["Viewer VCR"] = placementvdxsummaryfirst["Viewer VCR"].astype(str)
```